# How to write a unit test to verify my buffers(resources) are properly released

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm wondering how to write a good unit test verifying a buffer I allocate in a method is properly released under all circumstances. Generally this is what I am trying to achieve.

```
// Some pseudo code I imagine
public void performSomeIO() {
  // A better way may be to use try-with-resource but not everything is Closeable
  // Maybe you will say "Wrap it with a Closeable if it is not"?
  Buffer bytebuf = SomeUtility.allocateBuffer(...);
  try {
    // do some IO
    read(byteBuf);
  } catch (SomeException e) {
    // Some handling
  } finally {
    // I guess the rule of thumb is the buffer should be properly closed in the
    // finally section, but you cannot expect everyone to follow this pattern.
    // For example I find memory leak in an old program and I'd like to detect
    // that and add a guard on the scenario so that does not happen anymore.
    // Imagine this finally section does not exist, what kind of unit test do I add
    // to ensure the buffer is released? In other words, if someone removes the
    // finally section, the test will start alerting.
    bytebuf.release();
  }
}
```

I find it not easy to track resources that are only internal to a method. Are there any rule of thumbs, either regarding how to verify the lifecycle of internal resource(like buffer or more generally anything), or regarding how to avoid buffer leaks at a unit test level?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make `SomeUtility` an interface and `allocateBuffer` a method on that interface for better testability. You'll need to inject a `SomeUtility` instance into each component which allocates buffers.

Then you can test each method something like this (this test is written for JUnit 4):

```
class TestIoPerformer {
    @Rule
    public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    @Mock
    private SomeUtility someUtility;

    @Mock
    Buffer buffer;

    @InjectMocks
    private IoPerformer ioPerformer;

    @Test
    public void testBufferReleased() {
      when(someUtility.allocateBuffer(...)).thenReturn(buffer);
      // mock Buffer behaviour if necessary
      ioPerformer.performSomeIO();
      verify(buffer).release();
    }
}
```

This is just testing one path through your code. You will want a separate test for other paths, e.g. `read()` throwing an exception.

To make it easier for people to do the right thing, you can make your `Buffer` implement `Closeable` and encourage client to use the try-with-resources pattern.